# Determining how often and how long a specific event occurs in SQL data

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-series

I am curious how would be the best method to find out how often and how long an event occured within a set of SQL data that is managed using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.

Below is a simplified data table to illustrate the type of thing I'd be interested in solving. Say data is collected by a sensor for every 100ms and I want to know how often and how long the power dropped to 0.

I have a couple ideas how to do this using CTEs and/or Window functions, however my understanding of these functions doesn't seem to translate in SQL Management Studio as my code keeps tripping errors at points that should theoretically be correct.

For example I thought I could Window functions partitioned by the position number, filtered by the points when power was 0  then subtract the LAST_VALUE from the FIRST_VALUE. However the environment doesn't recognize these arguments.

I thought also about a CTE that already filters out the points where power was zero, but I couldn't bring that to a remotely functional point.

```
CREATE TABLE SensorData
(
    [TimeStamp] DATETIME ,
    [Position] INT,
    [POWER] INT
);

INSERT INTO SensorData ([TimeStamp], [Position], [Power])
VALUES (4, 1, 59), (101, 1, 60), (207, 1, 50), (321, 1, 58),
       (428, 1, 55), (534, 1, 59), (646, 1, 51), (755, 1, 0),
       (868, 1, 0), (975, 1, 0), (1081, 1, 0), (1193, 2, 45),
       (1307, 2, 52), (1412, 2, 51), (1519, 2, 55), (1629, 2, 58),
       (1735, 2, 0), (1851, 2, 0), (1960, 2, 0), (2066, 2, 54);

SELECT *
FROM SensorData;
```

How the output looks at the end isn't so important. What's important is I know the number of events where, in this case, the power went to zero and how long this event lasted (last TimeStamp within the event minus the first TimeStamp)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You need to assign a group to the "0" records.  A handy identifier for the group is the number of non-zero values before the value.  The rest is aggregation:

```
select position, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select sd.*,
             sum(case when power <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by position order by timestamp) as grp
      from sensordata sd
     ) sd
where power = 0
group by position, grp;
```

Note that this assumes that you want the `0`s per `position`.

Specifically because you are looking at `power = 0`, you can simplify the definition of the group:  it is the sum of the power up to that point.  This is constant for a group of adjacent rows with `power = 0`:

```
select position, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select sd.*,
             sum(power) over (partition by position order by timestamp) as grp
      from sensordata sd
     ) sd
where power = 0
group by position, grp;
```

Comment: Thats the method I was originally try for, thanks for clearing that and sorry for the late response

Answer (score 2):

Doing this in multiple CTEs to keep things nicely organized can be done as follows:

```
with sensorevents as (
    select
        [TimeStamp]
      , position
      , power
      , lag(power,1) over (order by timestamp) as prevPower
    from SensorData
)
, powerloss as (
    select
        *
        , case when [prevPower] > 0 and power = 0 then 'power loss'
               when [prevPower] = 0 and power > 0 then 'power on'
          end as status
        , case when [prevPower] = 0 then lag(timestamp,1) over (order by timestamp)
          end as powerOffTimestamp
        , case when [prevPower] > 0 and power = 0 then 0
               when [prevPower] = 0 and power > 0 then timestamp - lag(timestamp,1) over (order by timestamp)
          end as duration
    from Sensorevents
    where ([prevPower] > 0 and power = 0)
           or
          ([prevPower] = 0 and power > 0)
)
select
    *
 from powerloss
 where status = 'power on'
```

The first CTE defines a new column, `prevPower` which tells us if we are at an edge where power loss occurs or  power restoration occurs. The next CTE uses these edges and window functions again to find the timestamp where the previous event (loss) occurs for a power restoration event, and calculates the duration from the timestamp difference.

The last `select` statement just filters on the power restoration events:

```
TimeStamp   position    power   prevPower   nextPower   status  powerOffTimestamp   duration
09/04/1903 00:00:00 2   45  0   52  power on    26/01/1902 00:00:00 15/03/1901 00:00:00
29/08/1905 00:00:00 2   54  0       power on    02/10/1904 00:00:00 28/11/1900 00:00:00
```

I just saw that the other reply partitions by `position`. To add that to this solution, you need to modify all window functions by adding a `partition by position` clause:

```
      , lag(power,1) over (order by timestamp partition by position) as prevPower
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=264deed484604cda3ace1fb60d674068

Comment: Thank you, I knew of the 'case when' clause but could not properly implement the syntax (sorry for my ubels delayed response)